# Swiper slider in loop duplicate the pictures and Last slide not showing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, performance, swiper.js

I was using swiperjs to create a slider in which 3 images show at once and it will loop infinite, but when I added images to that slide it acts weird and began to show blank spaces after the last slide screenshot attached below:

[image: 1]

here's my HTML code same as the swiper documentation provided

```
<div>
 <div class="swiper mySwiper w-11/12 h-full">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper flex justify-center items-center ease-linear">
       <!-- Swiper Slides embedded using DOM -->
     </div>
 </div>
 <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
 <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
 <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

and now here is JavaScript

**First, I embed the images into the swiper-wrapper using the js script**

```
let images = ['img1.webp', 'img2.webp', 'img3.webp', 'img4.webp', 'img5.webp'];

  document.querySelector('.mySwiper > .swiper-wrapper').innerHTML = images.map((img,index) => {
    return `
    <div key="${index}" class="swiper-slide">
      <img
        class="block object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-xl"
        src="./images/${img}"
        alt="gallery"
      />
    </div>`
  }).join('')
```

**Then, I initialise the slider**

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    breakpoints: {
      // when window width is >= 480px
      1023: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
      },
    },
  });

  swiper.loopDestroy();
```